# Periodically on and off Raspberry Pi by controls with GPIO pins

Tags: pi-3

Is there any way to hibernate the raspberry pi and wake it up periodically without any physical contact but only controls through the GPIO pins?

Comment: Shut it down, yes. But how do you plan to wake it up by GPIO when it is off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There **NO** way to hibernate the Raspberry Pi.

It is either running or not. You can `poweroff` which leaves the Graphics Core running, but you need to restart.